# Input button onclick do not work in JSP

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, input

I test my issue in Firefox. I click the save button(it is a input, and the type is `button`), it ought to execute:

```
onclick="checkchar()"
```

but it did not.

[image]

My part of code in `jsp`:

```
<script language="javascript">
  function checkchar(){

  /*
    if(document.Form2.stationRun.value.length>2500){

        alert("站点运行情况字数不能超过2500字");
        return;
    }
    if(document.Form2.devRun.value.length>2500){

        alert("设备运行情况字数不能超过2500字");
        return;
    }
    */
  //alert('before...');
  document.Form2.action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/system/elecCommonMsgAction_save.do";
  document.Form2.submit();
  alert(" 待办事宜保存成功!");
  }

...
<input type="button" name="BT_Submit" value="保存" onclick="checkchar()" id="BT_Submit" style="font-size:12px; color:black; height:20px;width:50px">
```

I don't know why I click my save button, the method did not execute, some one can help me with this? and if is caused by the upload stylesheet (`http://localhost:8080/css/Font.css`)? I am not sure.

---

**EDIT**

Because the main framework is `frameset`, and the javascript methods and the input button is in my main page(you can see the below, which is in red rectangle I add). So use firebug it shows there do not contains any javascript code.

[image]

---

**EDIT -2**

The all code of my `actingIndex.jsp`:

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%--引入struts tags--%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s"  uri="/struts-tags" %>


<html>
<head>
<title>运行监控模块编辑</title>
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/css/Style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/css/showText.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script language="javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/script/function.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/script/limitedTextarea.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/script/showText.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"/>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ckfinder/ckfinder.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function checkchar(){

      /*
        if(document.Form2.stationRun.value.length>2500){

            alert("站点运行情况字数不能超过2500字");
            return;
        }
        if(document.Form2.devRun.value.length>2500){

            alert("设备运行情况字数不能超过2500字");
            return;
        }
        */
      alert('before...');
      document.Form2.action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/system/elecCommonMsgAction_save.do";
      document.Form2.submit();
      alert(" 待办事宜保存成功!");
  }
  function addEnter(element){
        document.getElementById(element).value = document.getElementById(element).value+"<br>";

  }
  function checkTextAreaLen(){
        var stationRun = new Bs_LimitedTextarea('stationRun', 2500);
        stationRun.infolineCssStyle = "font-family:arial; font-size:11px; color:gray;";
        stationRun.draw();

        var devRun = new Bs_LimitedTextarea('devRun', 2500);
        devRun.infolineCssStyle = "font-family:arial; font-size:11px; color:gray;";
        devRun.draw();
  }
  window.onload=function(){
        //checkTextAreaLen();
  }
</script>


</head>

<body>
<form name="Form1" id="Form1" method="post">
    <table cellSpacing="1" cellPadding="0" width="90%" align="center" bgColor="#f5fafe" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr height=10><td></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <TABLE style="WIDTH: 105px; HEIGHT: 20px" border="0">
                                    <TR>
                                        <TD align="center" background="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/images/cotNavGround.gif"><img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/images/yin.gif" width="15"></TD>
                                        <TD class="DropShadow" background="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/images/cotNavGround.gif">运行监控列表</TD>
                                    </TR>
                     </TABLE>
                  </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="ta_01" align="center" bgColor="#f5fafe" colspan=3>
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" rules="all" bordercolor="gray" border="1" id="DataGrid1"
                            style="BORDER-RIGHT:gray 1px solid; BORDER-TOP:gray 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT:gray 1px solid; WIDTH:100%; WORD-BREAK:break-all; BORDER-BOTTOM:gray 1px solid; BORDER-COLLAPSE:collapse; BACKGROUND-COLOR:#f5fafe; WORD-WRAP:break-word">
                            <tr style="FONT-WEIGHT:bold;FONT-SIZE:12pt;HEIGHT:25px;BACKGROUND-COLOR:#afd1f3">

                                <td align="center" width="40%" height=22 background="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/images/tablehead.jpg">站点运行情况</td>

                                <td align="center" width="40%" height=22 background="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/images/tablehead.jpg">设备运行情况</td>
                                <td align="center" width="20%" height=22 background="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/images/tablehead.jpg">创建日期</td>
                            </tr>
                            <div id="showInfomation" style="visibility: hidden"></div>
                            <tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor = 'white'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor = '#F5FAFE';">
                                <td style="HEIGHT:22px" align="center" width="40%">
                                    <div class="scrollStyle" align="left" onmouseover="showInfoWithPanel(this)" onmouseout="hiddenInfoPanel(this)" style="table-layout:fixed;">
                                        <s:property value="stationRun"/>
                                    </div>

                                </td>
                                <td style="HEIGHT:22px" align="center" width="40%">
                                    <div class="scrollStyle" align="left" onmouseover="showInfoWithPanel(this)" onmouseout="hiddenInfoPanel(this)" style="table-layout:fixed;">
                                        <s:property value="devRun"/>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="HEIGHT:22px" align="center" width="20%">
                                    <s:date name="createDate" format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>

                    </td>
                </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
<form name="Form2" id="Form2"  method="post">
    <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5" width="90%" align="center" bgcolor="#f5fafe" style="border:1px solid #8ba7e3" border="0">

        <tr>
            <td class="ta_01" colspan=2 align="center" background="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/images/b-info.gif">
            <font face="宋体" size="2"><strong>运行监控编辑</strong></font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr height=10><td></td><td></td></tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="ta_01" align="center" bgcolor="#f5fafe" width="15%">站点运行情况：</td>
            <td class="ta_01" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="word-break: break-all">
                <s:textarea name="stationRun" id="stationRun" cssstyle="width: 1000px; height: 160px; padding: 1px;FONT-FAMILY: 宋体; FONT-SIZE: 9pt" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13)addEnter('stationRun');"></s:textarea>
                <!--<script type="text/javascript">
                    CKEDITOR.replace("stationRun", {height:200, width:800});
                </script>-->

            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="ta_01" align="center" bgcolor="#f5fafe" width="15%">设备运行情况：</td>
            <td class="ta_01" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="word-break: break-all">
                <s:textarea name="devRun" id="devRun" cssstyle="width:1000px; height: 160px; padding:1px;FONT-FAMILY: 宋体; FONT-SIZE: 9pt" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13)addEnter('devRun');"></s:textarea>
                <!-- <script type="text/javascript">
                    CKEDITOR.replace("devRun", {height:200, width:800});
                </script> -->
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="ta_01" style="width: 100%" align="center" bgcolor="#f5fafe" colspan="2">
            <input type="button" name="BT_Submit" value="保存" onclick="checkchar()" id="BT_Submit" style="font-size:12px;  color:black; height:20px;width:50px">&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input style="font-size:12px; color:black; height:20px; width:80px" id="BT_Export" type="button" value="导出设置" name="BT_Export"
                         onclick="openWindow('${pageContext.request.contextPath }/system/exportExcel.jsp?belongTo=5-3','700','400')">&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You open script tag , But it is not closed,and 
 it is important to insert the script at the END of the page. So that the page 
 can register the controls first.

```js
function checkchar(){
        /*
          if(document.Form2.stationRun.value.length>2500){

              alert("站点运行情况字数不能超过2500字");
              return;
          }
          if(document.Form2.devRun.value.length>2500){

              alert("设备运行情况字数不能超过2500字");
              return;
          }
          */
        //alert('before...');
        //document.Form2.action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/system/elecCommonMsgAction_save.do";
        //document.Form2.submit();
        alert(" 待办事宜保存成功!");
    }
```

```html
<input type="button" name="BT_Submit" value="保存" onclick="checkchar()" id="BT_Submit" style="font-size:12px; color:black; height:20px;width:50px">
```

Comment: not that important to put at end of page when code only declares functions

Comment: @Mostafa Sabeghi I did not post all the script method in my post, so I did not copy the end script tag in it.

Comment: @244boy check your code with firebug,the method is executed,i guess you have javascript error in your code

Comment: @MostafaSabeghi How to check if there is error in javascript code? I use IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: @MostafaSabeghi The unloaded `css` will not cause this type issue, alright？

Comment: @244boy yes , you can delete all code in checkchar() except alert , and check that is executed,

Comment: @MostafaSabeghi I post some more information, you can see the EDIT and EDIT-2, and I try to delete all code in `checkchar()` except alert, but still not alert. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Try this checkchar() function

```
 function checkchar(){    
    alert("Hello");
 }
```